# windbg - how can I avoid the "Press Enter to continue"? when executing .shell

Tags: windbg

windbg - how can I avoid the "Press Enter to continue"?

```
0:031> .shell "${$arg2}" ProcessDV "${$arg1}"
<.shell waiting 1 second(s) for process>
.shell: Process exited
Press ENTER to continue
<.shell process may need input>
```

I don't want to use shell -x because I want to be sure to wait for the process to exit.  However, after the process exits I'd like to continue my script without user intervention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect stdin of the process.

syntax:

```
.shell -ci "windbg command/s separated by ;" windows_command arg1 arg2 ...
```

In crude sense, it's somewhat equivalent to:

```
windbg_commands | windows_command args1 arg2
```

where `|` stands for `pipe`.

---

If your windows_command does not take any input, use this syntax as follows:

```
.shell -ci "*" "${$arg2}" ProcessDV "${$arg1}"
```

Remember, `*` stands for comment. Thus it does not create any output.